# Send multiple data using href in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia

How to send multiple data using href in Aurelia?

```
This works: <a href="#/candidate/upload/${cid}?t=${item.heading}">
```

Just need the syntax.

```
Not working:<a href="#/candidate/upload/${cid}?t=${item.heading};s=${item.sw_casedocumentid}">
```

Comment: Try this `<a href="#/candidate/upload/${cid}?t=${item.heading}&s=${item.sw_casedocumentid}">`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the `route-href` custom attribute. I'm guessing you have a route configuration that looks something like this:

```
{ route: 'candidate/upload/:cid', name: 'upload', ... }
```

The cool thing with the router is that if you pass it parameters that don't exist on a route, it will just add them to the query string:

```
<a route-href="route: 'upload', 
               params.bind: { cid: cid; t: item.heading; s: item.sw_casedocumentid }"></a>
```

This will produce a link that looks how you want it to look.

Comment: Thanks Ashley for the better solution.

Answer (score 0):

Solution: Just need to add & between the data

```
<a href="#/candidate/upload/${cid}?t=${item.heading}&s=${item.sw_casedocumentid}">
```

Comment: You should prefer not building URL fragments by hand like this in Aurelia. Let the router build the links for you, that way your links won't break if a route were to change at some point.